# Adjusting map pointer image to exact location?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying a add map pointer image when the user clicks on the map . I was unable to drop the image at the exact location of the click. Instead, the center of the image is at the location not the bottom of it . How do I readjust such that I get the map pointer to it .

[image: Here is image]

```
 coordinateGraphic = new esri.Graphic(globalCoordinate, new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("./images/mappointer.png", 15, 35));
    globalMap.graphics.add(coordinateGraphic);
```